# How to assert if the image is zoomed in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

Using selenium with `java` I want to vary whether an image is zoomed when the cursor is moved over the image. From the source code below, element changes:

Before zoom: `<div class="powatag-zoom powatag-hidden">`

After zoom: `<div class="powatag-zoom">`

Any help to assert the change with working code is  welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach would be to check the value of `getAttribute("class")` before and after the mouse move action:

```
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.powatag-zoom"));
assertEquals(we.getAttribute("class"), "powatag-zoom powatag-hidden");

Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform(); 

assertEquals(we.getAttribute("class"), "powatag-zoom");
```

You can also check the size of the element using [`getSize`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize()).

Comment: Thanks It worked ... but i was hoping if you can help me write a function  for the above code .. that will be gr8.. as i dont have to put so many lines of code everytime i want to use it .

Comment: @user3616172 it is a good idea to make this code reusable if you are going to use it more than once. I'll refer you to a useful thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939601/how-can-i-add-code-reuse-to-my-selenium-tests, should help.